# JetBrain webstorm: UI changing tabs text color

Tags: webstorm

In webstorm, the user interface (not code editor section) is a dark grey and the text in the tabs is a dark blue, making it really difficult to read.  I haven't found where in the settings to change these colors.  Anyone?

Answer (score 29):

`File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `File Status`, **Modified**.

Comment: Thank you @CrazyCoder. Just to clarify, the tab colors didn't kick in on WS9 until I've exited the `File status` popup.

Comment: Yes, Just confirmed. After changing it in File Status, Modified. Even after you click on Apply, the text color in tab doesn't change until you click on OK to close the Settings dialog window.

Comment: I had to restart (pycharm) for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

php webstorm version have a small bug - you need to change the scheme and apply
then roll back to your scheme and apply - then you will see the change in file modified ...

Answer (score 0):

## 2022

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Version Control` | `File Status Colors`